# Обращение к символу в массиве строк

Tags: c++, строки, динамические-массивы, символы

Существует массив строк:

```
int q;
cin >> q;
string *s = new string[q];
for(int i = 0; i < q; i++) s[i] = "abc";
```

строчки непустые;

Суть вопроса: 
**Как обратиться к j-тому элементу i-той строки в массиве s?**

Comment: Как всегда - `s[i][j]`

Comment: значение типа "const char*" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "char"

Comment: Покажите свой код. Вы там не стали ли часом присваивать `s[i][j] = "abc"` (судя по сообщению об ошибке)? Так вспомните, что элемент строки - это **символ**, а `"abc"` - это **строка**...

Comment: Я разобрался со своей проблемой, благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос: Как обратиться к j-тому элементу i-той строки в массиве s?

Ответ: `s[i][j]`

Comment: значение типа "const char*" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "char"